# Trigger validations in real-time with jquery.validate

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I'm using to [jquery.validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to validate my forms.

The first-time validation only happens when I `focusout` the input. 
*If I come back to the same input already validated once, it validates as a write, in real-time.*

I have to `focusout` the input or submit it once to get real-time validations. **Is this a bug or a configuration issue?**

My validate.js file:

https://gist.github.com/4445364

Is there a way to get this behaviour as default?

Comment: Please post your code within the question to make it more "self-contained" and un-reliant on the status of external links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Is this a bug or a configuration issue?"

It's a configuration issue.  See below.

> "I have to 'focusout' the input or submit it once to get real-time validations.  Is there a way to get this behaviour as default?"

This is already the default behavior.  See this simple jsFiddle demo.  Just start typing in any field and you'll immediately see a message in real-time as you type.

http://jsfiddle.net/RXrKU/

**jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            field: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

**HTML:**

```
<form> 
     <input type="text" name="field" />
     <input type="submit" />
</form> ​
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can call $('form').validate().form() to get this behaviour